# How to turn off Windows 11 "Live Captions" (video to text)

Tags: windows-11, accessibility

When I play a YouTube video, something like this pop's up (turning the speech of the video into text or "captions" as they seem to call it. (I wouldn't call it captions, because captions should appear at the bottom of the video, not in a separate pop-up.)
[image]

From the best I can tell, I have turned it off on the "Accessibility" settings, yet it pops up again each time I open a new video on YouTube.

[image]

Comment: That appears to be something YouTube is displaying, if not, it’s an accessible feature that has been turned on. It’s called something along the lines of accessible description (AT)

Comment: Does it appear when using a particular browser or any?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Chrome.

1. Open Chrome Settings -> Accessibility.
2. Turn Live Caption off.

[image]

Comment: I'm on Windows 11 Pro, definitely not Chrome.

Comment: @NealWalters What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Chrome and Edge both, I don't specifically remember which one I was using last time that happened.  Today it is not happening in either browser. Next time I see it, I will report back; maybe what I did fixed it, but with was delayed until restart or next time browser was opened or something.